# Увеличение площади реакции на нажатие Checkbox (вокруг него)

Tags: android, checkbox, recyclerview, android-on-click

У меня есть RecyclerView, состоящий из списка Item'ов, многие (но не все) из которых имеют по одному CheckBox. Совсем не устраивает то, что чуть промазав мимо CheckBox, я получаю клик по его родителю, а не по самому CheckBox. Увеличение размера CheckBox или добавление еще одного Layout размерами больше CheckBox, для обработки кликов внутри него, не подходят как решение проблемы.

Как еще можно увеличить (да хотя бы просто сделать) радиус определения клика по пространству вокруг CheckBox (но внутри Item), как клика по CheckBox?

Comment: @metalurgus да, именно это и нужно. Жаль принять как ответ не могу

Comment: сами сформулируйте правильный ответ, дабы его отметили как отвеченный.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei не хочу отбирать лавры у metalurgus, все-таки помог он, а не я сам себе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы увеличить размер любого `View`, добавьте ему `padding`